# Para una barra de busqueda en ASP.NET ¿Como mando una lista de productos a un listbox a mi pagina de encontrados?

Tags: c#, asp.net, aplicación-web, asp, webforms

tengo una lista

```
List<Producto> producto = new List<Producto>();
```

que toma info de una clase que a su vez la recibe de la base de datos. En mi pagemaster tengo una barra de busqueda, con un boton de buscar. Este botón en WindowsForms me muestra la información en una listbox que está en el mismo formulario.

```
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            UpdateBinding();
        }
        private void UpdateBinding()
        {
            listaencotnrados.DataSource = producto;
            listaencotnrados.DisplayMember = "fullinfo";


        }
        private void BtnBuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataAccess bd = new DataAccess();

           producto = bd.GetProducto(txtBuscar.Text);
            UpdateBinding();
        }

    }
```

El problema es que en ASP tengo mi boton de buscar en la MasterPage, mientras que mi listbox (que después intentaré cambiarlo por un DataList), se encuentra en mi pagina Busqueda.aspx

El DattaAccess es una clase que me conecta con la base de datos

```
using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(helper.CnnVal("food")))
        {
            var output = connection.Query<Producto>($"SELECT * FROM PRODUCTO WHERE Nombre_prod = '{nombre}'").ToList();
            return output;
        }
```

(ignoren el SELECT, que pronto cambiaré por un StoredProcedure que realicé). Mientras tanto, el helper es una clase que me ayuda a acceder al ConnectionString a mi base de datos

```
public static string CnnVal(string nombre)
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[nombre].ConnectionString;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías tener en la MasterPage un botón:

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Y en la Page;

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = this.Master.FindControl("btn") as Button;
    btn.Click += new EventHandler(this.BtnBuscar_Click);
}

public void BtnBuscar_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   /*
     Se ejecutará cuando se haga click en el botón de la master page
     y tendrás acceso al ListBox o a cualquier control que utilices
     en Busqueda.aspx
   */
}
```

Lo que haces con esto es establecer que el método BtnBuscar_Click se ejecutará cuando suceda el evento Click en el botón en la Masterpage.

Comment: se ve bien. Lo haré, espero me será de mucha utilidad, gracias.

Comment: Si te sirvió, no olvides votar la respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: claro, soy nuevo en la plataforma, a penas me acaban de dar el privilegio de votar hehe